# Remove asterisk from only one field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom component that takes in values from an API and then displays them to a user, however within this component I give a 'required' flag to give an asterisk to the label, however I only want one field as seen below to have an asterisk not both as is currently happening.

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                        <SearchUsers
                            name="primaryOfficerId"
                            label="PO Responsible"
                            id="primaryOfficerId"
                            onSelect={change.bind(null, 'primaryOfficerId')}
                            error={touched.primaryOfficerId && Boolean(errors.primaryOfficerId)}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                        <SearchUsers
                            name="supportOfficerId"
                            label="Support Officer"
                            id="supportOfficerId"
                            onSelect={change.bind(null, 'supportOfficerId')}
                        />
                    </Grid>
```

And now my custom component

```
const Search = (props) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [select, setSelect] = useState(0);
const { type: TYPE, name: NAME, label: LABEL, onSelect, filter } = props;

const applyFilter = (data) => {
    let result = data;
    if (filter) {
        result = filter(data);
    }
    return result;
};

useEffect(() => {
    getLookupData(TYPE)
        .then((response) => {
            setData(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error === HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
                setData([]);
            } else {
                throw error;
            }
        });
}, [TYPE]);

const options = applyFilter(data).map((item) => (
    <MenuItem value={item.id} key={item.id}>
        {item[NAME]}
    </MenuItem>
));

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelect(event.target.value);
    onSelect && onSelect(event);
};

const { classes } = props;
return (
    <FormControl required className={classes.formControl} id={NAME} error={props.error}>
        <FormControlLabel control={<InputLabel htmlFor={NAME}>{LABEL}</InputLabel>} />
        <Select
            name={TYPE}
            value={select}
            onChange={handleChange}
            disabled={props.disabled || options.length === 0}
            input={<Input name={TYPE} id={NAME} />}
        >
            <MenuItem value="">
                <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            {options}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
);
};
```

Below you can see an image of my problem, both PO, and So responsible have an asterisk. I need only PO to have this asterisk but my component does not currently allow for individuals

[image]

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your component customizable by passing it a `required` prop as boolean then in your component make it dynamic :

```
<FormControl required={props.required}>
  // ... 
</FormControl>
```

So now you can use it with an asterisk `<SearchUsers required />` or without `<SearchUsers required={false} />`

Answer (score 1):

Add additional prop `required` to your `Search` component and then use it as a prop value for `FormControl`:

```js
<FormControl required={props.required} />
```